# How to compare all values in a column in Pandas.DataFrame with arbitrary value using specific function for comparison?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame which has filenames in first column and vector of decimal numbers in second column (which is of Pandas' type `Series`). DataFrame was loaded from CSV that looks like this:

```
,filename,vector
0,my-filename,"[1.2 3.1 2.6 ...]"
1,another-filename,"[1.1 3.3 2.2 ...]"
...
```

I have this function `scipy.spatial.distance.correlation(vec1, vec2)` and some input vector. I need to compare that input vector with every vector in DataFrame using specified function, and get *n* most correlated filenames.

Right now I am doing that by iterating over DataFrame, calculating correlations, saving results, sorting them and then taking *n* most correlated. I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/5440823) which basically says that iterating over DataFrame is bad (unless you have very good reason), so I am wondering if there is a better way. I can also adjust arrangement of data in DataFrame if needed.

So, how can one "vectorize" this?